# Alternative to jQuery Ui Dialog in IE7 Quirks mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a page that must run in IE7 quirks mode and was relying on jQuery UI Modal dialog until I realized this. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: There are 1000's of dialog scripts out there in the wild. Pick one...I guess you are [one of the 4%](http://theie7countdown.com/).

Comment: I'd just not use a dialog if the browser was in quirksmode, if that can even be detected.

Comment: It's sad to think that we are more successful at getting rid of IE7 than IE 6 :/ http://www.ie6countdown.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [custom js](http://jsfiddle.net/46jYC/3/) in such cases since it's more flexible. To center the div you should change onclick behaviour of the show button to following:

```
pos = get_scroll(); 
$("#dialog").css({ 
    'top': pos.y,
    'left': pos.x + window.screen.availWidth / 2,
    'margin-left': 50}
).show();
```

But you'll have to implement modal behaviour to complete this piece of code